# UL section is jumbled

Tags: jquery, html, css, inline, footer

I'm trying to figure out how to make the `<ul>` lists aligned within the inline boxes. I have 4 boxes with content, and the ones in the centre are perfect, but the ones on both the left and right side are uneven.

*I'm a beginner at HTML and CSS so I'm really confused on what to do.*

[What it looks like on Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBieH.png)

**This is what I have on CSS:**

```
.floating-box {
   float: left;
   width: 205px;
   height: 120px;
   margin: 20px;
   border: 1px solid #3B88AD; 
   padding-left:20px;
   padding-bottom: 165px;
   padding-right: 20px;
   background-color: #f2f2f2;
   font-family: open sans;
   font-size: 15px;
   color: black;
}

h1{
   padding-left: 20px;
   padding-top: 20px;
   font-family: open sans;
   text-shadow: 3px 1px #cccccc;
}

p {
   padding-left: 20px;
   font-family: open sans;
}

#skills{
   color: black;
}
```

**This is my HTML format:**

```
<div class="floating-box"><h4>Brand Identity</h4>
<p>Visual identity such as:
    <ul>
        <li id="skills">Letterheads</li>
        <li id="skills">Business cards</li>
        <li id="skills">Brand guides, and </li>
        <li id="skills">logos</li>
        <li id="skills">Research &amp identity</li>
     </ul>
</p></div>
<div class="floating-box"><h4>Package Design</h4>
    <p>
    <ul>
        <li id="skills"> Creating visually appealing and striking design.</li>
        <li id="skills"> Follwing the clients brief on their brand essence, 
        target audience, user personas, and color scheme.</li>
    </ul>
    </p></div>

 <div class="floating-box"><h4>Web Design</h4>
    <p>
    <ul>
        <li id="skills"><b>User Interface (UI) Design &amp User Experience 
        (UX):</b> 
        Analyzing how people navigate through a site, or app.</li>
        <li id="skills"><b>Interactive Design:</b> Creating mobile apps, 
        banner ads, &amp social media assets.</li>
    </ul>
    </p></div>

<div class="floating-box"><h4>Communcation Design</h4>
    <p>Designing marketing material such as:
    <ul>
        <li id="skills">Flyers</li> 
        <li id="skills">Brochures</li>
        <li id="skills">Postcards</li>
        <li id="skills">and Posters</li>
    </ul></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the code *here*, formatted correctly. Not as an image.

Comment: Try to put your current code in https://jsfiddle.net/. Run it. If it works, save and share us the url.

Comment: i think you whant study  ```https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp```

Comment: @DavodAslanifakor thank you! I added "clear:both" and "float: left" to the "#skills" section and they are aligned now.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine in my laptop in chrome and safari. You should try other browser if it works fine in other browser than there would be some problem in Firefox.